# Giving Journalists Draft Edit with the New 9.30 Permissions and $2sxc.cms.run

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am trying out the new permissions and $2sxc.cms API released in 2sxc 9.30.  My goal is to allow journalists to create new blogs, see/edit their drafts, but only allow lead editors to publish.

I have most features working: A journalist can add/edit an article and the article does get saved as draft for the editor to review.  However when an article is saved by the journalist a couple of unexpected dialogs appear:

1) An authentication dialog asks the journalist to enter their credentials
[image]

2) An error dialog indicates "Authorization has been denied" (I assume this is related to the first dialog)

Still the blog updates are saved. No exceptions appear in the DNN Admin logs.  Obviously 2sxc is trying to access some resource on behalf of the user, but what?

Here are the steps I have executed done so far:

1) Enabled "Permission by Group", "Permissions by User", "Public Forms", and "Public Forms File Upload"

2) Created a "Blog Journalist" security role.

3) Gave the "Blog Journalist" "Edit Draft CRUD" and "Read Schema" permission on ALL the Blog content types.

4) Gave the "Blog Journalist" "CRUD" on the Image field of the BlogPost

5) Gave the "Blog Journalist" "Read" permission on ALL the Queries (not sure that was necessary).

6) Created new queries and views that include drafts, put them on a special page that a "Blog Journalist" can access but "All Users" cannot. (I did this because the Publishing filter was not allowing drafts to be seen by my "Blog Journalist" role.)

7) Generated "Add Article" and "Edit Article" buttons using $2sxc.cms.run.

For reference here is the documentation I am following:

```
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/concept-permissions
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/javascript-%242sxc.cms
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/html-js-commands
https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/recipe-create-public-forms-with-2sxc
```

**I just need to get rid of these authentication dialogs. So what am I missing?**

Comment: Thought I solved it the other day by going to "Manage Apps in this Zone" "Features" and turning on "Custom WebAPIs save in ADAM" but nope.